# ngFor repeated components radio buttons scope is no isolated

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular-components

[image: I changed radio here]

[image: It refelcted here also but the model is still 'fail']

I have two components one is Post:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'post',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{postText}}</p>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let postData of posts">
         <news-feed></news-feed>
      </li>
     </ul>
    `
})
export class Post {
    title : string;
    postText : string;
    posts = [{title:"Post1",postText:"Wow greate post"}, {title:"Post1",postText:"Wow greate post"}]
    constructor(title:string, postText:string) {
        this.title  = title;
        this.postText = postText;
    }
}
```

the other is newsfeed:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'news-feed',
        template: `
        <h1>News Feed</h1>
        <div class="radios">
           <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="success" [(ngModel)]="commandResult.type (change)="getCommandResult()"> Succeeded
              </label>
           </div>
           <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="fail [(ngModel)]="commandResult.type (change)="getCommandResult()"> Failed
             </label>
           </div>
         </div>`
    })
    export class NewsFeed {
        commandResult: any = {
          type: 'fail'
        };
        constructor() {
        }
        getCommandResult() {}
    }
```

I am repeating news feed component in post component and when ever I change the radio button in one of the repeated components, I see that it changes in all the repeated components. Perhaps I am approaching this the wrong way as I am new to ang2. Any help is appreciated.
[In this link, I think I am facing similar issue, I know its angular1 but still the same issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/r9MLe/588/)

Comment: You need to learn about parent-child components interaction. Angular docs are a great source

Comment: @Vega Can you give some idea on what I wrong I am doing here? I looked into the docs and I couldn't find any related info.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component class:

```
export class Post {
    title : string;
    postText : string;
    posts = [{type:1, title:"Post1",postText:"Wow greate post"}, {type: 0, title:"Post1",postText:"Wow greate post"}]
....
```

parent template:

```
   <li *ngFor="let postData of posts">
         <news-feed [commandResult]=postData></news-feed>
    </li>
```

In the child component class:

```
import{Input) from "@angular/core"

export class NewsFeed {
      @Input() commandResult: any ;
      .......

      setCommandResult(value): void {
          this.commandResult.type = value;
      }
 }
```

And

```
  {{ commandResult.title }}
  <input type="radio" (change)="setCommandResult(1)" [value]="1" [checked]="commandResult.type===1">Succeeded
  <input type="radio" (change)="setCommandResult(2)" [value]="2" [checked]="commandResult.type===2">Failed
```

And [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) some reading

Comment: `<news-feed [data]=postData></news-feed>` in this line, did you mean `<news-feed [commandResult]=postData></news-feed>` as commandResult is the input parameter ??

Comment: I inpsected each object and the `commandResult.type` is different in the each object, but whenever I switch radio button, on the UI all the repeated radios are flipping. Looks like the ngModel has issues. any insights ?

Comment: I have attached the images in the question

Comment: It doesn't even work, the ngModel is not even changing.

Comment: That checks both the radio buttons. I am not sure why this is happening.